# how to prevent calling action method when previous page displays error box

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I need to display error message for radiobuttonfor using selection in mvc.
when Error pop up comes its hitting to next action method and moves to next page. how to prevent it . please help me.

For checking I tried this one. when Alert box appears its moving to next page.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnsave"  onclick="return checkform(this.form)" value="submit"/>

function checkform(form)
{
alert('hi');
return true;
}
```

Comment: Please add your javascript and html code

Comment: added... please check  @artemisian

Comment: no need to return again, change to onclick="checkform(this.form)"

Comment: I tried without returning anything..but its moving to next page

Comment: When you submit a form the browser (by default) will load the response of that request into the page. If you want to prevent the form submission then one way of doing it would be to have the 'checkform' function return false.

Comment: I return false but its moving to next page .... any other idea@artemisian

Comment: can you show your complete HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Returning false not making page to redirect. See the below code snippet.

```html
<script>
 function checkform(form)
{
alert('hi');
return false;
}
</script>
<form action="google.com">
<input type="submit" id="btnsave"  onclick="return checkform(this.form)" value="submit"/>
</form>
```